# How to send HTML emails in Outlook for Mac

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-outlook-2011

I'm not able to send HTML emails using Outlook for Mac.  The emails I send are all in plain text and not in HTML.

How do I change this?

Answer (score 3):

Outlook gives you the option for this... You have to go into the Outlook Preferences menu :

Outlook -> Preferences -> email -> create and make sure that you have checked one of the last ticks that says : compose email in html by default. Please find the following image, i'm sorry for the french version of my outlook, but I figure you should be able to follow the image for reference :
[image]